# DropDrown List not populating data in Spring Boot Mysql

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am  a beginner of spring boot. while i doing the login form ran ito the problem with unable to load the userrole in to the dropdown list. data will coming from mysql database.what i tried so far i attached below along with the screen shot.
i want to load the user role in to Dropdownlist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJo8j.jpg)

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/")
        public String lists(Model model) {
    
            
            List<User> liststudent = userService.listAll();

            model.addAttribute("liststudent", liststudent);

            return "login";
        }
```

**Service**

```
public List<User> listAll()
    {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
```

**UserClass**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="login")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    
    public User() {
        
    }
    
    
    
    public User(Long id, String username, String password, String role) {
    
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
     User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);

}
```

**Login Form**

```
   <tr> 
                <td>Role</td>
                <td>
                <select name="liststudents">
                    <option th:each="liststudents : ${liststudent}"
                    th:text="${liststudents.role}"
                    
                    />
                </select>

                </td>
            </tr>
```

Database Screen Shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ6XU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you're trying to get a list of all users, whereas you wrote that you just need a list of roles. The best way to solve it is to create an entity of Roles and get a list of them from the repository.

Comment: how to write the code sir. i don't know how to do it.

Comment: i attached database screen shot as well